# How to debug a DLL written in .NET/C#?

Tags: debugging, dll, .net, breakpoint, c#

I want to reverse engineer an application written in C#. I would like to set a breakpoint at a function and observe the input passed to it during the normal course of the application's functioning.

Comment: Please clarify your question. It is unclear what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

I've used [dnSpy](https://github.com/0xd4d/dnSpy) in production for debugging as it can be put on a USB.  It's perfectly capable of decompiling and debugging dll's.

[image: dnSpy screenshot]

It has a pretty rich set of features.  It's able to attach to running .net processes, decompile the code, edit variables at breakpoints and make some code changes on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: https://github.com/hexfati/SharpDllLoader

A simple C# executable that invokes an arbitrary method of an arbitrary C# DLL. The project is useful to analyze malicious C# DLL through the popular tool DNSpy.